# Assistance for my problem with my try catch implementation in calculator

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, bootstrap-4, calculator

I'm struggling with this vue, js calculator. Surprisingly, my output gets added to the expression after I do try and catch. How do I make it so that the ERR and the output goes to the {{output}}. Need some help please!

[image: Example 1:]

[image: Example 2:]

here is the part

```
                else if (but == "=") {
                    try {
                        eval(this.expression)
                        // this.output = eval(this.expression)
                    } catch (error) {
                            this.output = "ERR"
                            // throw e;
                        }
                }
```

Full code here

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>calculator</title>

    <!-- Vue 3: development -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css"
        integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app" class="container" style="width: 400px;">

        <div class="row border m-3 text-right" style='height:100px;'>
            <div class="col">
                {{expression}}
                {{output}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col">
                <template v-for="i in button.length">
                    <button id="button[i-1]"class="btn btn-light m-2" style="width:50px" @click="action(button[i-1])">
                        {{button[i-1]}}
                    </button>
                    <br v-if=" i % 4 == 0">
                </template>
            </div>
        </div>

            

        </div>


    </div>

</body>

<script>
    Vue.createApp({
        data() {
            return {
                expression: "",
                output: "",
                button: ["1","2","3","AC", "4", "5", "6", "+", "7", "8", "9", "-", "0", ".", "="]
            };
        },
        methods: {
            action(but) {
                console.log(but)
                if (this.expression == "" && (but ==  "+" || but =="-")){
                    this.expression = "0" + but
                }
                else if (but == "=") {
                    try {
                        eval(this.expression)
                        // this.output = eval(this.expression)
                    } catch (error) {
                            this.output = "ERR"
                            // throw e;
                        }
                }
                else{
                    this.expression = this.expression + but
                }
                // if =
                if (but == "AC") {
                    this.expression = ""
                    this.output = ""
                }
            }
        },
        computed: {
        }
    }).mount('#app')

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed my error, its just a lack of `<br>`. :( omg i spent so long debugging

```
                {{expression}}
                <br>
                {{output}}
```

[image: supposed output]